# Overriding OnInit in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I want to override OnInit function in Asp.Net Web forms using Visual Basic.
Code below is how it is overridden using C#. I found it pretty unclear how to do it in VB.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

I have managed to convert only function, not content

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: still can't convert it

Comment: Use `AddHandler` for the `Page_Load` event. And use `MyBase` To call the base class method.